# MultiThreading with searchbox

Tags: c#, database, wpf, multithreading

I have a listbox with list of persons (first name ,last name , addresses...) and a searchbox (TextBox with TextChaned event 
the thing is i'm running a search throw database and it take a long time and the UI freeze for seconds ...so,how can I make it responsive ?

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Complete & Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *Async Await Pattern* is the common solve to this, or reactive extensions for debouncing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are working with DataTables, here is what you can do:

```
private async void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // async is important
{
    DataTable dt = await Task.Run(() => // await is important (avoids the UI freeze)
    {
        return GetData(); // Fetch your data from DB
    });
    // Fill your listbox with the data in dt
}
```

Comment: That works as magic !!! thank you very much ...unfortunately I'm still a beginner so I can't vote ...really appreciate that

Comment: @Bakaji happy that I helped. :-) Just be aware that `GetData()` will run in another thread. Don't put any UI related code inside this call.